# How to display archive by selecting year and then selecting month

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, archives, custom-post-type-archives, archive-template

I'm trying to build my archive page to have a row of years and a row of months. The user would then have to select a year and then select a month and a gallery of posts would be generated. I have an example image below of what I want. How could I achieve this?

I've searched online and I can't find anything similar to this. I have added a mockup html and css of how it should look, but I just can't figure out how to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated! I have a code pen of the html and css here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/egpZqr

what I want...
[image]

my current `page-archive.php`

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-html -->

<?php
get_header(); ?>

<div class="page-header">
  <h1>ARCHIVE</h1>
</div>
<div class="archive-block">
    <span class="archive-block__alert">
        Please Select A Year First  </span>
    <ul class="archive-block__list archive-block__list--year">

                    <li class="archive-block__item ">
                <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--year " data-year="2009">
                    2009                </span>
            </li>
                    <li class="archive-block__item ">
                <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--year " data-year="2010">
                    2010                </span>
            </li>
                    <li class="archive-block__item ">
                <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--year " data-year="2011">
                    2011                </span>
            </li>
                    <li class="archive-block__item ">
                <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--year " data-year="2012">
                    2012                </span>
            </li>
                    <li class="archive-block__item ">
                <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--year " data-year="2013">
                    2013                </span>
            </li>
                    <li class="archive-block__item ">
                <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--year " data-year="2014">
                    2014                </span>
            </li>
                    <li class="archive-block__item ">
                <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--year " data-year="2015">
                    2015                </span>
            </li>
                    <li class="archive-block__item ">
                <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--year " data-year="2016">
                    2016                </span>
            </li>
                    <li class="archive-block__item ">
                <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--year archive-block__selector--current-year" data-year="2017">
                    2017                </span>
            </li>

    </ul>

    <ul class="archive-block__list archive-block__list--month">
                        <!-- printf('<option value="%u">%s</option>', $num, $name); -->
            <li class="archive-block__item">
                <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--month archive-block__selector--current-month" data-month="1">
                    Jan             </span>
            </li>
                        <!-- printf('<option value="%u">%s</option>', $num, $name); -->
            <li class="archive-block__item">
                <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--month " data-month="2">
                    Feb             </span>
            </li>
                        <!-- printf('<option value="%u">%s</option>', $num, $name); -->
            <li class="archive-block__item">
                <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--month " data-month="3">
                    Mar             </span>
            </li>
                        <!-- printf('<option value="%u">%s</option>', $num, $name); -->
            <li class="archive-block__item">
                <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--month " data-month="4">
                    Apr             </span>
            </li>
                        <!-- printf('<option value="%u">%s</option>', $num, $name); -->
            <li class="archive-block__item">
                <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--month " data-month="5">
                    May             </span>
            </li>
                        <!-- printf('<option value="%u">%s</option>', $num, $name); -->
            <li class="archive-block__item">
                <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--month " data-month="6">
                    Jun             </span>
            </li>
                        <!-- printf('<option value="%u">%s</option>', $num, $name); -->
            <li class="archive-block__item">
                <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--month " data-month="7">
                    Jul             </span>
            </li>
                        <!-- printf('<option value="%u">%s</option>', $num, $name); -->
            <li class="archive-block__item">
                <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--month " data-month="8">
                    Aug             </span>
            </li>
                        <!-- printf('<option value="%u">%s</option>', $num, $name); -->
            <li class="archive-block__item">
                <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--month " data-month="9">
                    Sep             </span>
            </li>
                        <!-- printf('<option value="%u">%s</option>', $num, $name); -->
            <li class="archive-block__item">
                <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--month " data-month="10">
                    Oct             </span>
            </li>
                        <!-- printf('<option value="%u">%s</option>', $num, $name); -->
            <li class="archive-block__item">
                <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--month " data-month="11">
                    Nov             </span>
            </li>
                        <!-- printf('<option value="%u">%s</option>', $num, $name); -->
            <li class="archive-block__item">
                <span class="archive-block__selector archive-block__selector--month " data-month="12">
                    Dec             </span>
            </li>
            </ul>
</div>


<div class="archive-block__empty-con">
    <span class="archive-block__empty">
        That combination is empty! Please select a different combination    </span>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

and css

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-css -->

.archive-block {
    float: none !important;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 930px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.archive-block__alert {
    display: none;
}
.archive-block__list {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}
.archive-block__list--month {
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
}
.archive-block__empty-con {
    text-align: center;
}


.archive-block__item {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0 23.5px;
}

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to nest [`wp_get_archives`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives) to achieve this, so you will have to build your own loop using [`get_month_link`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_month_link) Like this (untested, regard this as a starting point):

```
$year = 2009; 
while ($year =< get_the_time('Y')) {
  echo '<ul>'
  $month = 1;
  while ($month =< 12) {
    $link = get_month_link ($year, $month);
    if ($link != '') {
      echo '<li>' . $link . '</li>';
      }
    $month = $month + 1;
    }
  echo '</ul>';
  $year = $year + 1;
  }
```

Beware that `get_month_link` doesn't test if there actually are posts to display in that month. So the link will never be empty, unless you use the [`month_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/month_link/) filter to do that test and in that case return an empty link.

Next you'll need the css to display this ordered list correctly, but that is not a WP question.

Comment: How would I add this code to my php file? Just put php tags around it? Sorry I'm still a bit new at this, so I'm not the best.

Comment: Yeah, it's php.